# w3wp.exe Garbage Heap is FULL of Free object space and keeps on growing

Tags: memory-leaks, garbage-collection, heap-memory, w3wp.exe

My IIS app (.NET 4.0, IIS7) is continually growing in memory, and eventually falls over, as if I have a memory leak.

So I took a DMP while it was up around 1.7GB and cracked it open in WinDbg.

The dumpheap -stat command showed that while I had a fair amount of objects in the heap, the majority (and bit that is growing when looking at sequential DMPs) is labelled as "Free" (>800MB):

> 000007feef55b768    46091      2212368 System.Data.DataRowView
>   000007fe9739dda8    10355      2236680 Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty
>   000007fef4260610    33062      2644960 System.Signature
>   000007fef4242250    41809      4682608 System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
>   000007fef424f058    69232      8847997 System.Byte[]
>   000007fef4241b28       11      9437680 System.Double[]
>   000007fef4237ca0       15      9505176 System.DateTime[]
>   000007fef424c168    32559     11009308 System.Char[]
>   000007fef424dc30    17271     11795376 System.Int32[]
>   000007feef555c48      908     17936672 System.Data.RBTree`1+Node[[System.Int32, mscorlib]][]
>   000007feef554f58      853     22056952 System.Data.RBTree`1+Node[[System.Data.DataRow, System.Data]][]
>   000007feef5514b0   541444     51978624 System.Data.DataRow
>   000007fef424aee0  1550958    132599872 System.String
>   000007fef422f1b8   183607    178409288 System.Object[]
>   0000000000d8b2d0   234017    844500226      Free

So I then ran "!dumpheap -type Free" which gave me a *lot* of tiny Free objects (94 bytes each to be exact!) and towards the end a couple of larger "Free" objects:

> 00000003098a59b0 0000000000d8b2d0      134 Free
>   00000003098c19d0 0000000000d8b2d0      102 Free
>   00000003098ffa00 0000000000d8b2d0       54 Free
>   0000000309a41d98 0000000000d8b2d0  5961750 Free
>   000000041f8a1000 0000000000d8b2d0       24 Free
>   000000042001b4d0 0000000000d8b2d0 16933078 Free
>   00000004211bf7c8 0000000000d8b2d0     7702 Free
>   00000004212c1600 0000000000d8b2d0 35173374 Free
>   00000004236b3be0 0000000000d8b2d0    66886 Free
>   0000000423cc41e8 0000000000d8b2d0 10778318 Free
>   0000000424768928 0000000000d8b2d0  2254734 Free
>   00000004249ec128 0000000000d8b2d0 21166350 Free
>   000000042600f1e0 0000000000d8b2d0    51366 Free
>   000000042621bac8 0000000000d8b2d0 114007238 Free

```
Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
000007fef31e7460        1           32 System.Net.SafeLocalFree
0000000000d8b2d0   234017    844500226      Free
Total 234018 objects
```

Noting the repeating address of "d8b2d0" I ran a "!gcroot d8b2d0"
 to which I got the following result:

> 0:000> !gcroot d8b2d0
>   Found 0 unique roots (run '!GCRoot -all' to see all roots).

So... after all that... I have masses of Free objects stuck on my heap that the GC is not releasing. This builds up over about 2-3 hours. There is no other sign of any memory leaks from actual typed objects. It happens over almost all of our VMs in production.

Does anyone have any idea how to deal with the GC leaving so much Free object space on the heap?

It's had me running in circles for days. So hat's off to the genius that can help me figure this one out!

Comment: Is this an Asp.Net application? Any particular framework or library used?

Comment: yes it's asp.net. It's mostly DataTables and some local WCF using net.pipe.

Comment: Do you have any interop code or code that allocates `GCHandle`s directly? I'm thinking that maybe you have a lot of *pinned* objects that are preventing compaction.

Comment: I think this could be the issue, but I'm determin to discover exactly what the source is... the Datatables (or more specifically, a certain way of using then) or WCF or something else!?  https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/large-object-heap-compaction-should-you-use-it/

Comment: No interop code I'm aware of. Plus if it was pinned, wouldn't the gcroot find a root?

Comment: use PerfView and select "Take Heap Snapshot from dump". Now open the generated gcdump file in PerfView to see a nicer overview: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion on using PerfView by [magicandre1981](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1466046/magicandre1981), and after quite a few very large memory dumps, I've located this issue down to the use of DataRow.DefaultIfEmpty() in a Linq expression. It was part of a support function for carrying out a LeftJoin between two DataTables.

With the DefaultIfEmpty() in the DataRow enumeration as part of the Linq expression, I could recreate memory sky rocketing to 4GB+ in minutes. Most of this survives through to the Gen2 GC collection through sheer volume of ItemArrayObjects being created (both small and large object heap). This in turn lead to an ever climbing committed memory value. The GC2 collection just can't keep up on the small heap, and the large heap suffers from poor (if any) reuse.

We've taken this call out and the same recreation never gets more than 50MB in committed memory. We now need to see what the impact of this is on our DataTable joins, but the memory heap mystery has been solved!

Thanks for the help folks.

Comment: Can you state the steps you took to reach that conclusion? I'm struggling to find a cause in a very much similar situation.

Comment: Start by downloading and learning how to take memory dump files for managed code. There is a more extensive setup for triggering them as and when crashes happen or performance limits are exceeded, but I just attached the debugger to my app when it  started (and then again when it inflated) and created snapshot memory dumps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools

Comment: Then, I loaded the memory dumps in to PerfView (as noted above) and it was easy to browse around the objects. Comparing the first snapshot with the latter you start to see a pattern of certain types of objects causing the inflation in memory.

Comment: Somewhere on the web I found guidance on what type of objects cause the most 'survival' issues where they persist in to GC2 even when no longer believed to be in use. Well I found that when you use the DefaultIfEmpty on a DataRow, it creates an interim ItemArrayObjects object which never gets marked as dead as it is associated with the DataRow, in turn the DataTable and in turn the DataSet - so until I dispose of my dataset, that call will generate more surviving garbage.

Comment: As for finding that hot spot in your code, it took some trial and error to remove calls and isolate the inflation. I would say it was identifying that the ItemArrayObjects were the source of the garbage that led me to find that the DefaultIfEmpty() call was the likely culprit, as I wasn't doing anything in the code myself with respect to that type of object, ergo, it must be something DataRow related.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed steps. In my case i definitely see a kind of objects that seem responsible for the inflation - and they belong to a structure that is static, so it will not go anywhere, although the objects themselves may be released - but the worst is really the "free" space, in my case is above 1GB. In your case you saw a correlation between the heavy use of certain objects and heap fragmentation. I'm not really sure that's the case in my example. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that your app has memory leak i would suggest that you start local analysis with memory profiler. This might reveal the source of the problem faster than analyzing memory dumps in production.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been through all that. There are no memory leaks, which is what has lead me to investigate a memory DMP file instead. From the analysis above, it comfirms (I believe) that indeed there isn't a memory leak. Otherwise that large 800MB+ chunk would have a gcroot or at least an object type of some sort. Instead it's actually labelled as *free* but the GC just won't release it!?